# Basis of NGitLab: connect to a project & upload files

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab

I want to do some basic operations (create repo, checkout and commit files) in a GitLab project with [NGitLab](https://github.com/ubisoft/NGitLab) librairy and i struggle with using it.
In every examples, a "docker context" is used but i don't get if it's mandatory or not and how to get things done without it:

```
public async Task Test_get_file_with_bom()
    {
        using var context = await GitLabTestContext.CreateAsync();
        var project = context.CreateProject();
        var filesClient = context.Client.GetRepository(project.Id).Files;

        var fileName = "test.md";
        var fileUpsert = new FileUpsert
        {
            Branch = project.DefaultBranch,
            CommitMessage = "dummy",
            Encoding = "base64",
            Content = Convert.ToBase64String(new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0x61 }), // UTF8 BOM + 'a'
            Path = fileName,
        };
        filesClient.Create(fileUpsert);

        var file = filesClient.Get(fileName, project.DefaultBranch);
        Assert.That(file.Content, Is.EqualTo("77u/YQ=="));
        Assert.That(file.DecodedContent, Is.EqualTo("a"));
    }
```

Comment: `i struggle with using it` is not a problem statement we can assist with.

Comment: And what about ```I want to do some basic operations (create repo, checkout and commit files)``` ?